# Typescript: ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property '[variable]' of undefined

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, error-handling

I have an array of `LoginData` objects, one attribute of which is email. The following function takes a string parameter and is supposed to check whether there already exists a `LoginData` object with a matching email adress. Here is the code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LOGINDATA } from '../mock-users';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CheckLoginDataService {
  emailString: string = "";
  loginData = LOGINDATA;


  checkLoginData(str: string){
    let emailExists: boolean = false;

    this.loginData.forEach( function(LoginData){
      this.emailString = LoginData.email;
      console.log(this.emailString);

      if (str === this.emailString){
        emailExists = true;
      }
    })

    return emailExists;
  }
}
```

When I run my code I the Error:

> "ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'emailString' of undefined".

I looked at the other stackoverflow threads discussing this problems and they suggest to initialize `"emailString"` (in my case). I think I am doing that in the beginning already - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: use an arrow function instead of normal one

Comment: user arrow function of ECMAScript 6. this answer will hlep you https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/4281154

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`this.loginData.forEach( function(LoginData){`

to

`this.loginData.forEach((LoginData) => {`

Using arrow functions within a class binds `this` within the function to the class instance itself.